# objective c mask animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, mask

I want to make an animation as below. It is like Angry Birds Game's settings wheel button.

I used images to describe my problem.

I can rotate the wheel

[image]

and I can up the image (set_bg.png).

[image: set_bg.png]

startup position:

[image]

end position (after clicked the wheel):

[image]

as you see on startup position, I want to hide above wheel but I couldn't do. How can I do this animation?

I tried that code:

on ViewDid:

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"set_bg.png"];

maskLayer.contents = (id)maskImage.CGImage;
maskLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,92,219);
maskLayer.frame =CGRectMake(0,-135,92,219);
btn_setting_bg.layer.mask = maskLayer;
btn_setting_bg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

on wheel touched:

```
  CGRect position;
    CGRect oldBounds;
    CGRect newBounds;
    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    if(isSubMenuOpened == YES){
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2*M_PI];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0f];
        position = CGRectMake(btn_setting_bg.frame.origin.x,btn_settings.frame.origin.y + 6, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.width, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.height);
        newBounds = CGRectMake(0,-135,92,219);
        oldBounds = CGRectMake(0,0,92,219);
        isSubMenuOpened = NO;

    }else{
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
        position = CGRectMake(btn_setting_bg.frame.origin.x,btn_setting_bg.frame.origin.y - btn_setting_bg.frame.size.height -13 + btn_settings.frame.size.height, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.width, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.height);

        oldBounds = CGRectMake(0,-135,92,219);
        newBounds = CGRectMake(0,0,92,219);

        isSubMenuOpened = YES;

       // NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"x:%f,y:%f", position.origin.x, position.origin.y]);
    }



    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         [btn_setting_bg setFrame:position];
                         //[btn_setting_bg.layer.mask setFrame:CGRectMake(0,500,92,219)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"scale.y"];

                         animation2.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:oldBounds];
                         animation2.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newBounds];
                         animation2.duration = 1.2f;

                         btn_setting_bg.layer.mask.frame = newBounds;
                         // btn_setting_bg.layer.mask.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,92,219);
                         [btn_setting_bg.layer.mask addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"scale.y"];
                     }];


    animation.duration = 1.2f;
    animation.repeatCount = 1;
    [btn_settings.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try animating the `alpha` property of `wheel` from `0.0f` to `1.0f`.

Comment: but I don't have any problem with wheel. the second image goes up with animation. the problem is on startup position I need to hide the second image.

Comment: the alpha property makes it invisible at first (0.0f) and then slowly lose transparency until you can see it normally. Therefore this is an answer - but @paulrehkugler, it would be a better answer if you explained it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem using alpha. It is not what I exactly I want but this is also a good solution.

Thanks to @paulrehkugler and @kate-gregory

Now my code is as simple as:

```
 CGRect position;

    CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    if(isSubMenuOpened == YES){
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2*M_PI];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.0f];
        position = CGRectMake(btn_setting_bg.frame.origin.x,btn_settings.frame.origin.y + 6, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.width, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.height);
        isSubMenuOpened = NO;

    }else{
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
        position = CGRectMake(btn_setting_bg.frame.origin.x,btn_setting_bg.frame.origin.y - btn_setting_bg.frame.size.height -13 + btn_settings.frame.size.height, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.width, btn_setting_bg.frame.size.height);



        isSubMenuOpened = YES;


    }



    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         [btn_setting_bg setFrame:position];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     }];


    animation.duration = 1.2f;
    animation.repeatCount = 1;
    [btn_settings.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];


    if(isSubMenuOpened == YES){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:3.5 animations:^(void) {
            btn_setting_bg.alpha = 1;
        }];
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^(void) {
            btn_setting_bg.alpha = 0;
        }];
    }
```